# Limit the number of explode elements in list

Tags: php, explode

Hi i have this line of code below

```
list($tag1, $tag2, $tag3, $tag4, $tag5) = array_pad(explode(',', $new_shout_tags, 5), 5, "");
```

It, basically assigns no value to the elements in the list if there is nothing else in the `$new_shout_tags`. So basically if i have

```
$new_shout_tags = "asd, asdf, asdfg";
```

then list will be

```
$tag1 = "asd";
$tag2 = "asdf";
$tag3 = "asdfg";
$tag4 = "";
$tag5 = "";
```

Which is all good however if the user enters

```
$new_shout_tags = "asd, asdf, asdfg, asdaf, asdafa, afads, asdasfd";
```

Which is 7 elemnts for example then the explode creates this in the list

```
$tag1 = "asd";
$tag2 = "asdf";
$tag3 = "asdfg";
$tag4 = "asdaf";
$tag5 = "asdafa, afads, asdasfd";
```

How do i make it not include the last 2 or however many over 5 that the user has entered, just the first 5 only.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a garbage variable.

```
list($tag1, $tag2, $tag3, $tag4, $tag5, $garbage) =
    array_pad(explode(',', $new_shout_tags, 6), 6, "");
```

Comment: Very clever I didn't even think of that

Comment: It's great for processing lists where the data comes in chunks, you can simply split out the number of bits you need at the time and leave the rest in the garbage/remainder variable to deal with later.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
$v1=explode(',', $new_shout_tags); // with no limit
$v2=array_slice($v1,0,5);
$v3=array_pad($v2, 5, "");
list($tag1, $tag2, $tag3, $tag4, $tag5) = $v3
```